# "Поклонимся", призыв, ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

В призывном обращении "Давайте поклонимся..." ударение всё равно падает на второй слог, а не на И?

Comment: В какам смысле "все равно"? Это форма будущего времени, по-другому её невозможно трактовать. С чем вы сравниваете?

Comment: Я сравниваю с обычными сочетаниями: "мы поклонимся". Подумал, вдруг в призыве, т. е. в сочетании с "давайте", "пойдёмте" и др., меняется ударение.

Comment: Нет, с какой стати? Форма одна, семантика та же, фразеологизма не образует, сочетанием сущестивительного с предлогом тем более не является. А других причин для смещения ударения внутри одного слова и одной формы я даже не знаю... Вы бы писали такие вопросы подробнее, а то в ступор вгоняет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ударение на О, покл**о**нимся. В любом, естественно, сочетании. Словари здесь, при такой постановке вопроса, ни при чем. В русском (да, наверное, и в любом сколько-нибудь известном) языке ударение **в одной форме** не смещается в зависимости от контекста, если это не омографы, конечно, и не фразеологизм.

Иначе просто трудно было бы, даже невозможно составить классификационную парадигму по имеющимся формообразующим критериям (у нас - вид, время, лицо). Вот как тут это делается.
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F
*Я привожу для того, чтобы указать принцип построения парадигмы, а не как авторитетный источник орфоэпии. Хотя в общем-то викисловарю и в этом можно доверять, он построен на данных Зализняка, системных ошибок быть не должно, только опечатка разве.*

Comment: А когда говорят "косить травУ", это точно ошибка? Просто мне тоже так нравится.))

Comment: Почему же? В винительном именно травУ. И никак иначе. Здесь идет смещение на флексию при склонении, я же не об этом говорил. Трава и траву - это разные формы (падежные в данном случае), поэтому и ударение может быть различным.

Comment: О, и точно! Что не может не радовать.) Пускай это другой случай, но всё-таки близкий, решил заодно узнать, спасибо!

Comment: Правильно, я всё напутал, *трАву* считается неправильным. Тогда противоположный вопрос: *"лечь на трАву"* однозначно неправильно? Просто я подумал от том, что если б не было правила, то я бы колебался, что выбрать: *лечь на трАву или на травУ.*

Comment: Однозначно. Можно еще встретить в поэтической речи "нА траву", но это другое, хотя тоже неправильно. А "на трАву" - никаким нормам не соответствует. Ну максимум - просторечие.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus, запомню.)

Answer (score 1):

В призыве "Давайте поклонимся..." используется форма глагола будущего времени. Ударение от значения не меняется. Во всех словарях, в т.ч. и И у Зализняка, и в БАСе везде покло́нишься, покло́нятся,покл**о**нимся.